# How to access different array data in onItemSelected?

Tags: android, spinner, onitemclicklistener

I'm trying to implement multiple spinners within one activity, which appears to be working ok. The problem I have is when I'm trying to output their options using onItemSelected, I can't work out how to tell this method which spinner was just updated. I'll copy the code in but here is the extract from the onItemSelected method. Which for example if I had two spinners would only show me results from intTypeItems spinner.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(intTypeItems[position]);
}
```

Here is the full Class I'm working with.

```
public class Calculator extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TextView selection;
    private static final Integer[] intNoItems={1,2,3};
    //private static final String[] intNoItems={"one","two","three"};
    private static final String[] intTypeItems={"Seconds","Minutes","Hours","Days"};    

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
    Spinner intNo=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intervalNo);
    Spinner intType=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intervalType);

    intNo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    intType.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.outPutValues);

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> intNolist=new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,intNoItems);
    ArrayAdapter<String> intTypelist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,intTypeItems);

    intNolist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    intTypelist.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    intNo.setAdapter(intNolist);
    intType.setAdapter(intTypelist); 
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    selection.setText(casting + intTypeItems[position]);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

One of the spinners is a int the other a string, so I'll also need to cast the int to string when outputting to my selection text view. Which again I'm not sure how to do, as the cast would cause an exception when the string gets the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have everything you need. Look at the call:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id);
```

That first parameter, `parent`, contains the `View` that the item belongs to. In your case, it will either be `intNo` or `intType`. If you kept those variables as fields, you could then test to see which `Spinner` you were in, like this:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    if(parent == intNo) {
        selection.setText(casting + intNoItems[position]);   
    } else if(parent == intType) {
        selection.setText(casting + intTypeItems[position]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of this, looks like code I understand which is good for me as this Java is hellishly confusing! anyway, I have tried it but my Eclipse is complaining about intNo and intType not being resolved as variables?

Comment: That's why I said "if you kept those variables as fields". See the `private TextView selection;` line? Create `Spinner intNo;` and `Spinner intType;` there and change the usage in your `onCreate()` to `intNo=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.intervalNo);`

Comment: Awesome, sorry I have no idea what variable as fields means, but from the rest of your reply I understand what was wrong, I needed to move the declaration of the intNo and intType Strings outside of my method.(I am learning here) Anyway I've done that and it works a treat. thanks very much. now on to the maths :)

Comment: Excellent, good luck. A "field" is a variable that belongs to the object. Moving the declaration into the class definition turned those variables from just local variables to fields that the entire object has access to.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, very detailed and easy for me to understand. hope to see your advice again :)

Answer (score 1):

You have attached same listener to both spinners.  Clean way may be use different listeners for each of them

```
 intNo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new FirstListener());
 intType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SecondListener());
```

write two separate inner classes, FirstListener and SecondListener

OR

anonymous innerclasses something like below

```
intNo.setOnItemSelectedListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Your code here.
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't work these solutions out. I think at this point in my Java experience I'd need a larger example to show how this ties together. I would also want minimum amounts of code, and your 2st example suggests doubling up of code?